# Laravel 4.2 Dropdown List

Tags: php, select, laravel

I want to populate a select input using data stored in my database.

I have **firstname** and **lastname** fields for my clients and I want to display **fullname** (both firstname and lastname) on the dropdown list.

I'm using `Client::lists('firstname', 'id')` to generate the list. Apparently this will only show the firstname only.

How do I combine the two fields in the above code, or is there a better alternative to this?

Another related question, how do I set the first option to be **--please select a client--** instead of getting the first client straight away on top.

Comment: Are you using Form facade to generate your form (and your dropdown)?

Comment: Yes, I am. Terry Low's answer has solved it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you define your accessor by adding the following code to your user model

```
public function getUserNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->lastname} {$this->firstname}";
}
```

and query your model this way

```
$list = User::get(['firstname','lastname','id'])->lists('username','id');
```

regard the --please select a client-- ,

you may do a array merge or 
do a plus like so

```
Form::select('list',['0'=>'--please select a client--'] + $list);
```